# Editor framework in GWT datagrid

Tags: gwt, datagrid, uibinder

I am using GWT 2.5.1 datagrid with listdataprovider, list data provider is updated using RPC call, but now i wanted to use the Editor framework for GWT, can somebody please provide me some pointers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already take a look at the documentation, it's pretty good:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html

You will need a CompositeEditor if you want to use it inside a datagrid to hook up the path to your elements.